# Poor efficiency for multiple simulations

Tags: r, performance

I have an R code for a general stochastic SIR model, and I am trying to create a final size distribution plot for 10,000 simulations for this one. But, my R code is running really slow, I can even leave it on overnight and my code still hasn't finished. So I am just wondering a little bit about why this is and if there is something I can do about it? My guess is that it is a bad algorithm but I am not sure since it works fine for around 100 simulations. I will put my code for the SIR model and the 10,000 simulations below for the one who is interested. Thanks in advance!

```
rSIR <- function(T, beta, gamma, n, m, l) {
  t <- 0
  x <- n # Susceptibles
  y <- m # Infectious
  z <- l # Recovered
  
  # Possible events
  eventLevels <- c("S->I","I->R")
  # Initialize result
  events <- data.frame(t=t,x=x,y=y,event=NA, z=z)
  # Loop
  while (t < T & (y>0)) {
    beta <- if(t <= 10) {b} else if(t <= 60) {b*0.6} else if(t > 60){b*0.8}
    # Draw
    wait <- rexp(2,c("S->I"=beta*x*y,"I->R"=gamma*y))
    # Which event occurs first
    i <- which.min(wait)
    # Advance time
    t <- t+wait[i]
    # Update population
    if (eventLevels[i] == "S->I") {x <- x-1; y <- y+1; z <- z}
    if (eventLevels[i] == "I->R") {y <- y-1; z <- z+1}
    # Store results
    events <- rbind(events,c(t,x,y,i,z))
  }
  events$event<- factor(eventLevels[events$event], levels=eventLevels)
  return(events)
}

# SET VALUES 

b <- 1e-04
gamma <- 1/5
S0 <- 5000
# (R0 <- beta*S0/gamma)
T <- 500
nSim = 1

# SIMULATE AND PLOT

set.seed(124)

trajs <- lapply(1:nSim, function(x) {
  rSIR(T, beta=beta, gamma=gamma, n=S0, m=1, l=0)
})

trajsas <- lapply(1:10000, function(x) rSIR(T, beta=1e-04, gamma=1/5, n=5000, m=1, l=0))
first <- lapply(trajsas, function (x) `[`(x, c('z')))
f <- c()

for (i in first) {
  for (j in i) {
    ö <- length(j)
    f <- c(f,j[ö])
  }
}

ggplot(data=NULL, aes(x = f, y=..count../(sum(..count..)))) + 
  geom_histogram(bins=30, colour = "navyblue", fill = "white") + expand_limits(x=c(0,5000)) +    
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1), limits = c(0, 1)) +
  labs(x="final size", y = "frequency")
```

Comment: in general, rbind is SLOOOOW for large objects. Try creating the data frame empty at the final size and just fill it in the loop.

Comment: Ohh that's a bummer. Thank you for your answer, I will try that!

Comment: Said again and with a ref and an alternate approach: Iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(old, newrow)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). For each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.

Comment: you could see if there's any efficiency gain in replacing your `lapply()` with `replicate(10000, rSIR(T, beta=beta, gamma=gamma, n=S0, m=1, l=0))`

Comment: Notice that the parameter `beta` passed to `rSIR` is unused before it is reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

For these types of simulations, I've found that vectorizing over the replications can be much faster. Here is one way for `rSIR`:

```
library(data.table)

simSIR <- function(tMax, b, bt, g, s, i, n) {
  # function to simulate SIR model
  # INPUTS:
  #   tmax: the maximum time of the simulation
  #   b:    array of time-dependent beta parameter values
  #   bt:   transition times for beta values (length(bt) == length(b) - 1)
  #   g:    gamma parameter value
  #   s:    vector of the number of initial susceptibles for each replication
  #   i:    vector of the number of initial infectious for each replication
  #   n:    vector of the total population for each replication
  # OUTPUT: a data.table with 5 columns, sorted by rep then tm:
  #   rep:  the replication number
  #   tm:   time of the initial model state and all model state transitions
  #   s:    the number of susceptibles
  #   i:    the number of infectious
  #   r:    the number of recovered
  
  # determine the maximum number of model states for each replication (all
  # susceptibles become infectious, and all infectious recover)
  maxIter <- max(2L*s + i) + 1L
  # initialize the lists that will hold the model states of all replications
  # for each iteration
  ls <- vector("list", maxIter)
  li <- vector("list", maxIter)
  lt <- vector("list", maxIter)
  lrep <- vector("list", maxIter)
  # store the initial model state for each replication
  ls[[1]] <- s
  li[[1]] <- i
  lt[[1]] <- numeric(length(s))
  lrep[[1]] <- 1:length(s) # the repliation ID
  iter <- 1L # initialize the current iteration
  
  while(length(li[[iter]])) { # run the simulation
    # identify which replications are not complete
    iKeep <- which(li[[iter]] > 0L & lt[[iter]] < tMax)
    iter1 <- iter + 1L
    # keep the incomplete replications
    ls[[iter1]] <- ls[[iter]][iKeep]
    li[[iter1]] <- li[[iter]][iKeep]
    lt[[iter1]] <- lt[[iter]][iKeep]
    lrep[[iter1]] <- lrep[[iter]][iKeep]
    iter <- iter1 # increment the iteration count
    # random 0,1 for each replication, indicating if an infectious recovered;
    # take advantage of the fact that P(rexp(1, a) < rexp(1, b)) = a/(a + b)
    bsg <- b[1L + findInterval(lt[[iter]], bt, left.open = TRUE)]*ls[[iter]] + g
    r <- rbinom(length(iKeep), 1, g/bsg)
    # update the model state;
    # take advantage of the fact that pmin(rexp(n, a), rexp(n, b)) is
    # equivalent to rexp(n, a + b)
    lt[[iter]] <- lt[[iter]] + rexp(length(iKeep), li[[iter]]*bsg)
    ls[[iter]] <- ls[[iter]] - 1L + r
    li[[iter]] <- li[[iter]] - 2L*r + 1L
  }
  # unpack the lists into a data.table
  iter <- 1:iter
  setorder(
    data.table(
      rep = unlist(lrep[iter]),
      tm = unlist(lt[iter]),
      s = unlist(ls[iter]),
      i = unlist(li[iter])
    )[
      # calculate the number of recovered
      , r := n - s - i
    ][
      # remove rows after the maximum time
      tm < tMax
    ], rep, tm # order by replication ID, then by time
  )
}
```

Time 10k replications with the OP's inputs:

```
b <- 1e-4
g <- 0.2
nreps <- 1e4L
S0 <- 5e3L
system.time(dt <- simSIR(500, b*c(1, 0.6, 0.8), c(10, 60), g, rep(S0, nreps), rep(1L, nreps), S0 + 1L))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   10.27    1.59    7.56
```